# Using \return command in python function

Tags: python, doxygen

I'm trying to document a function in my python code and want to include the `\return` command. Lets say like this:

```
## \file
# File description

## Function to show you the problem.
#
# \return boolean True
def retTrue():
  return True
```

When I run doxygen on this it creates an entry in the corresponding file, but it just places the text `"Function to show you the problem."` next to the function. The function itself isn't linked and the `\return` command isn't used.

If I set `EXTRACT_ALL = YES` it works (means the function name is linked and a description block also showing the return text is created), but I'm sure there's a more elegant way to get this done without having every file of the project listed.

I tried `\return` for a class method, there it works immediately, so I guess I just can't figure out which is the correct option to set. The other `EXTRACT_` options didn't work for me.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me the magic setting.